# converting .csv to db in python withsqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

i get TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given),
when i convert show_id and genre into list of tuples, i get ValueError: paramenter are of unsupported type.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

# create database 
conn = sqlite3.connect("favorites8.db")

open("favorites8.db", "w")
db = conn.cursor()

# create table
db.execute("CREATE TABLE shows (id INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))")

db.execute("CREATE TABLE genres (shows_id INTEGER, genre TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (shows_id) REFERENCES shows(id))")

# open csv file 
with open("favorites.csv", "r") as file:
    # create dictreader
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    # iterate over csv file
    for row in reader:
        # canonicalize title
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()
        # insert title
        stmnt1 = "INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES(?)"
        show_id = db.execute(stmnt1, (title,))
        
        # Insert genres
        for genre in row["genres"].split(", "):
            stmnt2 = "INSERT INTO genres (shows_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)"
            
            db.executemany(stmnt2, show_id, genre)
    # commit changes
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
# end with
```

Comment: Can you please share the content of favorites.csv?

Comment: Timestamp,title,genres
10/28/2019 15:03:45,Dynasty,"Drama, Family"
10/28/2019 15:04:48,The Office,Comedy
10/28/2019 15:09:00,Blindspot,"Action, Crime, Drama"
10/28/2019 15:09:02,24,Action
10/28/2019 15:09:02,Friends,Comedy
10/28/2019 15:09:05,psych,Comedy
10/28/2019 15:09:09,Veep,Comedy
10/28/2019 15:09:09,Survivor,Reality-TV
.....

Comment: `db.executemany(stmnt2, show_id, genre)` should be `db.execute(stmnt2, (show_id, genre))`.  `executemany` is for when you want to insert / update / delete multiple sets of parameters in a single statement.

Comment: This also generates sqlite3.InterfaceError: error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed some mistakes and cleaned this up a bit:

```py
conn = sqlite3.connect("favorites8.db")

db = conn.cursor()

db.execute("CREATE TABLE shows (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL)")

db.execute("CREATE TABLE genres (shows_id INTEGER, genre TEXT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY (shows_id) REFERENCES shows(id))")

with open("favorites.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        title = row["title"].strip().upper()

        stmnt1 = "INSERT INTO shows (title) VALUES(?)"
        db.execute(stmnt1, (title,))
        show_id = db.lastrowid

        # Insert genres
        data = []
        stmnt2 = "INSERT INTO genres (shows_id, genre) VALUES(?, ?)"
        for genre in row["genres"].split(", "):
            data.append((show_id, genre))

        db.executemany(stmnt2, data)
    # commit changes
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

There were a bunch of issues:

1. `executemany` accepts iterable as a second argument.
2. First execute statement does not return id, but cursor object, you need to retrieve it manually.

Comment: Thanks, this works as expected, though i have to comment the first conn.commit(). Thanks again.

Comment: And show id is null.

Comment: @AbuAminu change to CREATE TABLE shows (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT NOT NULL) this is the correct way